# How can I load balance users access to 3 images of a database on different 3 servers?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 images of the same **sql server database** on 3 different servers.
I need a technique that helps me get the user accesses the database image with the least access load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd have one big server with plenty of RAM.

There isn't much call for load balancing in SQL Server: how do you handle writes?
If you don't have writes, you can optimise your one big server even more...

Anything you do is 100% custom: I also doubt there is an off-the-shelf product to help you

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need a fourth balancer server (or simple you need balancer-script on one of your server, which will do same as balancer server).
All queries must go to that root server.
Server must contain counters of requests to each of the three DB servers.
When you chose server, you must chose server with lowest load, and after that you need increment count of request to this server.